# Why does this code no longer show the value of my text boxes?

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP. 2 days ago I write few lines of code that was working, but yesterday, it wasn't anymore. The code was:

```
<body>
    <form method='post' action='test.php'>
        name <input type='text' id='txtName'/>
        age <input type='text' id='txtAge'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
        <hr/>
        name <?php echo $_POST['txtName']; ?>
        age <?php echo $_POST['txtAge']; ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

What it does is only to show the value of text boxes, but it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use name attribute on your input tags not ID for your php post variables:

```
<body>
<form method='post' action='test.php'>
    name <input type='text' name='txtName'/>
    age <input type='text' name='txtAge'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
    <hr/>
    name <?php echo $_POST['txtName']; ?>
    age <?php echo $_POST['txtAge']; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Use both name and id I would recommend :) Name is a must, of course but I think it would be alright to give a unique id to all input tags as well.

Comment: The ids would be useless unless you require the elements to be targets for some DOM fiddling or as selectors for CSS. Personally, I hate litering html with IDs that serve no purpose.

Comment: Ids in forms are actually serving a great purpose in terms of accessibility.  Using <label for="someID">some input</label><input id="someID" name="something" /> is great for users using screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `name` instead of `id`:

```
<body>
    <form method='post' action='test.php'>
        name <input type='text' name='txtName'/>
        age <input type='text' name='txtAge'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
        <hr/>
        name <?php echo $_POST['txtName']; ?>
        age <?php echo $_POST['txtAge']; ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

- First confirm that this code is in same file(test.php) as described in form's action attribute because you are using same file for input and display posted data.
- In **$_POST['name']**, it uses **name** of input field not **id**.

**If you still want to keep id in form attributes:**

```
<body>
    <form method='post' action='test.php'>
        name <input type='text' name='userName' id='txtName'/>
        age <input type='text' name='userAge' id='txtAge'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
        <hr/>
        name <?php echo $_POST['userName']; ?>
        age <?php echo $_POST['userAge']; ?>
    </form>
</body>
```